# Jquery Datatables issue with Data property

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using JQuery DataTables (version 1.10.0) , I am using "Data" property of DataTable to assign  data. Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').dataTable( {
    "data": jsonData2,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "extn" },
        { "data": "start_date" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ]
  } );
 } );
```

I wanted to update data on click of some button , i am using below code , but throwing error "Cannot reinitialize DataTable"

```
 function updateData() {
   $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "data": jsonDataUpdated
});
```

}

If I use same code written in document ready and with extra property "bDestroy": true
in updateData() function working fine .

Please suggest if above is correct way of updating data.

How this will work if i have huge data say around 5000+ records (please suggest if any better approach)

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: Did your jsonDataUpdated result return like this => http://www.sitepoint.com/working-jquery-datatables/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for updating single row without refreshing you can use [fnUpdate](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnUpdate) api or [fnRowCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnRowCallback).
here is another link around this topic in data table forum [fnUpdate](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9874/updating-rows-without-refreshing) and [fnRowCallback](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5096/ajax-to-update-single-row-on-table-using-one-time-ajax-load)

Edit:
for refreshing whole table you ca use [fnReloadAjax](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax) and here is [some tips for using datatables with very large data sets](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8789/tips-for-using-datatables-with-very-large-data-sets).

Comment: I wanted to update entire data with new data not just single row.